# Ajax:CalendarExtendar in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, calendarextender

I have a gridview, in the footer of gridview,I add a Textbox(TB1) and a CalendarExtendar(CAL1).
CAL1 has properties : PopupControl ID and targetControl ID = TB1.

When I click TB1 Popup of Calendar Extendar show the view of calendar.
But i found error : The Saturday is missing. So CAL just show 6 days.

Can anyone help me, why the saturday is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I started using the Ajax Calendar Extender.

For me the issue was with the CSS. If I remember correctly, the padding / margin between the columns is too large, so the last column doesn't fit within the viewable area.

Try tweaking the CSS. I'm pretty sure that Saturday is actually there, you just can't see it.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion JustABitOfCode.
The problems are on CssClass and I have fixed the CSS

Answer (score 0):

I used below CSS to fix the problem. The second line is optional.

```
div.ajax__calendar_container, div.ajax__calendar_body { width:225px; }

.ajax__calendar_days td { padding:2px 4px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following CSS , and it worked for me

```
.ajax__calendar_container TD
{
padding: 0 2px;
}
.ajax__calendar_container
{
width: 192px;
height: 178px;
}
.ajax__calendar_body
{
padding: 2px;
margin: 0px;
width: 192px;
}
.ajax__calendar_other,ajax__calendar_day,ajax__calendar_dayname
{
width: 15px;
height: 17px;
 margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.ajax__calendar_days, .ajax__calendar_months, .ajax__calendar_years {

width: 192px;
}
.ajax__calendar_day {
cursor: pointer;
height: 17px;
padding: 0 2px;
text-align: right;
width: 17px;
}
```